Como enviar correo electrónico que incluya una imagen pegada en un div con Google App Script
básicamente intento hacer algo parecido al modal de Gmail donde redactamos los correos; ya ven que puedes pegarle imágenes y estas se mandan como parte del cuerpo del correo.
Pues es eso, pero en Google Sheet para que redacte el correo con una plantilla y esta se rellene con la información que tiene la hoja, parte que ya funciona y esta en producción.
El detalle es con lo de la imagen por que se necesita poder tomar una captura de pantalla a un chat (como evidencia) y luego pegar esa captura en el modal y esta imagen se incluya en la plantilla del correo.
El problema es que no puedo hacer que se mande la imagen.
Aquí incluyo la parte de mi código que tiene relevancia (el mecanismo de lo de la imagen quite todo lo demás)
Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y su apoyo.
Codigo.gs
function correos(imagen){

var data = {imagen};

const plantilla = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("correo.html");

plantilla.dato = data;

var html = plantilla.evaluate().getContent();

GmailApp.sendEmail("someemail@somedomain.com","Subject","",{htmlBody:html});

}

Modal.html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myText" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <button onclick="send()">mandar</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    function send(){
       var editElem = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().correos(editElem);
       google.script.host.close(this);
    }
  </script>
</html>

Correo.html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="ima();">
    <h2> Test</h2><br />
    <div id="ima"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function ima(){
    document.getElementById("ima").innerHTML += <?=dato.imagen?>;
    }
  </script>
</html>




El punto aparte mejora los textos y su comprensión.
